# Can I start a PHP RecursiveIteratorIterator RecursiveDirectoryIterator at a certain point?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

Can I start a RecursiveIteratorIterator at a certain key? My code is:

```
$rootpath = 'mydir/';
$fileinfos = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootpath),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);
$i = 0;
foreach($fileinfos as $pathname => $fileinfo) {
    if($i++ < 15000) continue;
    var_dump($pathname);
}
```

This skips the first 15,000 filenames (which is what I want) but is obviously very slow, as it has to 'find' the point to start at.

I have looked everywhere for documentation, and can't find an answer. Is there a way to start the RecursiveIteratorIterator from key 15000 ? Something like $fileinfos->setKey(15000) ?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use `array_slice($your_array,15000);` and your array starts after `15000`

Comment: Thanks, but this would require reading all files into an array, and would take just as long as my initial code.

I also have tried this:
    $limit = new LimitIterator($fileinfos,160000);
but it still reads all results into an first, to determine where to start

Comment: I also note that RecursiveDirectoryIterator has the method seek() which does what I want, BUT doesn't seem to work with RecursiveIteratorIterator.

For example, if I do $dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootpath); $dir->seek(15000); $fileinfos = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir);
it doesn't work (it only seeks within the initial children, not the further leaves)